# bluetoothctl No default controller available

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

It's a bit wired here.

I have a problem is bluetoothctl always said "No default controller available". I found there are many people had same problem with me. But the situation is a bit different from them.

I can see my hciconfig -a have information like below
[image]

And hcitool dev seems no problem as well.
[image]

But I have no idea why my bluetoothctl always said "No default controller available"
[image]

Even when I turn down and turn up hci0 several times. It always in the same problem.

BTW, my BlueZ is 5.39.  And I tried this experiment on buildroot. Kernel is 3.10

Comment: Try 'btmgmt power off' followed by 'btmgmt power on' and see what happens. Also, if you have btmon installed, try running that in the background using 'btmon &' and see what happens when you run the 'bluetoothctl' commands.

Comment: Did you check whether "bluetoothd" is running. Sometimes distribution socket activates the "bluetoothd" daemon, but sometimes not based on systemd service file. Check "ps -ef | grep bluetoothd", if not running, start it. bluetoothctl uses "DBUS API" internally to get these details from "bluetoothd"

Comment: general "how do I get bluetooth to work in linux" question should be on [unix.se]

Comment: The same problem: "No default controller available" The main trouble was: I changed in "sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/main.conf" these lines to true: "KernelExperimental = true" and "Experimental = true". Then I shuffled a bit around (install and uninstall blueman, etc.) and now it is playing. But I do not understand the magic behind... :-)

Answer (score 58):

Had the same problem. Use:
`$ sudo bluetoothctl`

Then the controller was found automatically. I also tried https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=207025 before. Maybe this effected the solution.

Comment: for a solution using group privileges see one of the posts below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53738121/9486871)

Comment: Not necessarily the best idea. One, because it is [*probably* not needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63880031/5395338), and two, there are [risks for superfluous use of `sudo`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545768/whats-wrong-with-using-sudo). **Disclosure:** I up-voted this answer, then discovered the actual issue (group membership) was due to the fact that RPi OS Lite has an [**odd default**](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/116843/83790) here. Lesson learned: most popular answer not always best answer.

Answer (score 38):

Also happens if rfkill switch is blocking Bluetooth (for some inadvertent reason, in my case):

```
$ rfkill list all

0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

To unblock, pass the ID for your Bluetooth device from the list above to the `unblock` subcommand:

```
$ rfkill unblock 0
```

Then controller should be back:

```
$ bluetoothctl list
Controller .... [default]
```

Comment: do you know how to make this config persistent?

Comment: Don't know, not happening for me anymore. Maybe look into `rfkill-unblock@[index]` systemd service from `util-linux` package. But, I don't have it enabled fwiw.

Answer (score 15):

Here are the steps that worked for me by modifying the bluez config and the run without sudo:

- Create a "bluetooth" group which will be granted with `<allow send_destination="org.bluez"/>`  on bluez's d-bus config

> $ sudo groupadd bluetooth

- Open the config in /etc/dbus-1/system.d/bluetooth.conf  with your favorite text editor

   e.g.

> $ sudo vi /etc/dbus-1/system.d/bluetooth.conf

- Add/append the following lines below in /etc/dbus-1/system.d/bluetooth.conf

  `<policy group="bluetooth">`

  `<allow send_destination="org.bluez"/>`

  `</policy>`
- Save your changes.
- Add your login user to "bluetooth" group

> $ sudo usermod -a -G bluetooth <loginuser>

- Reboot the system.
- Then try to use "bluetoothctl" without sudo

  > $ bluetoothctl 
  >   [bluetooth]# show

Comment: Dare I ask what distro requires such thorough modification? IMO this should never be necessary.

Answer (score 8):

Its an old thread, but might help someone looking for answers.

I have faced this problem most of the times, and the things I verify are:

1. **systemctl status bluetooth**  == this checks if the bluetooth service daemon is already running or not. 
   Check for output:
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running)
   If not, start it using the command:  **sudo systemctl start bluetooth**
2. using **sudo bluetoothctl**

one of these two was the culprit usually.

Comment: The status shows it's loaded and running but when I do `sudo bluetoothctl` it says "Agent registered" and opens a sub-program thingy (the next line starts with `[bluetooth]# ` and prompts me to type commands. When I type `scan on` to look for devices it says "No default controller available".

Comment: I was in the state described by David, and a simple reboot fixed it for me.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem with **VanillaArch** on **Linux Kernel 5.12.** After struggling for a day I found the problem is:

**1. Some of bluetooth devices firmware are not available in the new linux libraries right out of the box and you need to find.** for this problem you can refer to the following repo. In readme it's well documented what you should do. basically you 'd download and copy the frimware in

> /lib/firmware/brcm

for  Broadcom Bluetooth devices.
https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware

**2.  Activation of two conflicting services on Bluetooth.**
Referring to "SayantanRC" on Arch froum :

> When I compared between the two, I found these two services were enabled on my Manjaro installation, but disabled on my Arch linux installation:

```
blueman-mechanism.service
bluetooth-mesh.service
```

> Disabled them and rebooted.

```
sudo systemctl disable blueman-mechanism.service
sudo systemctl disable bluetooth-mesh.service
```

> Now the services are as below:

```
~ >>> systemctl list-unit-files | grep blue                                                                                                                                           
blueman-mechanism.service                  disabled        disabled     
bluetooth-mesh.service                     disabled        disabled     
bluetooth.service                          enabled         disabled     
dbus-org.bluez.service                     alias           -            
bluetooth.target                           static          -            
~ >>>
```

> And voila, bluetooth is up!

```
~ >>> bluetoothctl                                                                                                                                                                    
Agent registered
[CHG] Controller 68:07:15:DE:1F:15 Pairable: yes
[bluetooth]# show
Controller 68:07:15:DE:1F:15 (public)
    Name: src-manjaro
    Alias: src-manjaro
    Class: 0x00000000
    Powered: no
    Discoverable: no
    DiscoverableTimeout: 0x000000b4
    Pairable: yes
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Headset AG                (00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0537
    Discovering: no
    Roles: central
    Roles: peripheral
Advertising Features:
    ActiveInstances: 0x00 (0)
    SupportedInstances: 0x05 (5)
    SupportedIncludes: tx-power
    SupportedIncludes: appearance
    SupportedIncludes: local-name
[bluetooth]# quit
```

> EDIT: For verification purpose, I re-enabled the services and
> bluetooth adapter was having trouble again. I disabled them and it is
> fine now. Checked on kernel 5.9 and 5.4.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=259260&p=2

Comment: Thank you! My bluetooth was fine for quite some time but today it suddenly stopped. Turns out I installed blueman at some point and removing it solved my problems!

Answer (score 3):

[The answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53738121/5395338) probably works on some distributions, but may get you into trouble in others. Unfortunately, it seems that every distribution has a different default configuration for Bluetooth - it's a pretty awful mess IMHO.

Here's what worked for me on a Debian derivative Raspberry Pi OS (née Raspbian):

As a preliminary check, on many distros you can check `/etc/group` to see if a group name `bluetooth` exists:

```
$ cat /etc/group | grep blue
```

If it exists, you obviously don't need to add the group, only add users to the group:

```
$ sudo usermod -G bluetooth -a <username>
```

In the distro I'm using, this was all that was required to make the Controller responsive in `bluetoothctl`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After a long research found out that the driver was not installed. Check that answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/545019/bluetooth-doesnt-work-in-debian-10 and see if your drivers are installed correctly =)