# Bluetoothctl - no default controller available

Tags: bluetooth

On bluetoothctl, anything I do returns with "No default controller available". I have tried [bluetoothctl No default controller available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48279646/bluetoothctl-no-default-controller-available) but it doesn't help.

hcitool dev shows nothing:

`Devices:`

output of `btmgmt power on`:

`Set Powered for hci0 failed with status 0x03 (Failed)`

`hciconfig hci0 up` doesn't work either:
`Can't init device hci0: cannot assign requested address(99)`

I'm using bluez 5.50.

I tried rfkill list, but bluetooth was not blocked. Here is the output of  `dmesg | grep Blue` :

````
[    6.417329] usb 1-7: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[    8.468387] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    8.468409] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    8.468413] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    8.468416] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    8.468423] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    9.634178] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    9.634180] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    9.634187] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   10.560211] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   18.656216] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI_OP_READ_LOCAL_VERSION failed (-110)
[  356.544055] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1001 tx timeout
[  364.735232] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI_OP_READ_LOCAL_VERSION failed (-110)
[  496.555828] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  496.555836] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  496.555844] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11```
````