# Bluetooth not working on raspberrypi 4 : no controller available

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, wifi

I've been trying to get my bluetooth to work but I don't even see the icon for it.
When I restart the pi and check the status I get:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo modprobe btusb
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-08-26 11:18:10 EDT; 2s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 1444 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─1444 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
```

I saw somewhere to do the modprobe thing which then makes the bluetooth active until I restart the pi, at which point it just reverts to inactive.
When I turn the bluetooth on I just get a no controller available message:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available
```

Based on similar questions I've seen the following asked for so here it is:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lspci
00:00.0 PCI bridge: Broadcom Limited Device 2711 (rev 10)
01:00.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VL805 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 01)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lspci -k
00:00.0 PCI bridge: Broadcom Limited Device 2711 (rev 10)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
01:00.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VL805 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: VIA Technologies, Inc. VL805 USB 3.0 Host Controller
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsmod | grep blue
bluetooth             376832  11 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,btusb
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
rfkill                 28672  6 bluetooth,cfg80211
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 258a:0001  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:0005 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I also messed up at some point while troubleshooting and tried this which did not fix anything but messed up my wifi so i no longer get network options to connect to I just get the 2 blue arrows that indicate that I'm connected but when I click on it to change the network I get no interfaces found and eth0 is down.

```
sudo apt install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

I would really appreciate help with fixing this. I need it for a time sensitive project and I've tried everything (within reason as someone who has no idea what they're doing)

Comment: What do you get when you try "hciconfig -a"? This question has a few suggestions that may be helful:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48279646/bluetoothctl-no-default-controller-available

Comment: Most comments on similar problems suggest to either start bluetoothctl with sudo (i.e. sudo bluetoothctl) or specifically enabling hciuart with this (systemctl start hciuart)

Comment: @YoussifSaeed I don't get anything when I try "hciconfig -a". I've already tried most of the things suggested in the post you linked. I've tried the "systemctl start hciuart", it asks for a password but nothing happens after. Sudo bluetoothctl doesn't make a difference.

Comment: OK can you try the list of commands here (https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=247721), specifically the ones posted on Aug 04, 2019 at 10:09. If that doesn't work, try this: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=96001 (Jan 09 2015, 3:00am)

Comment: If you're desperate, I would recommend buying an HCI dongle that can be attached to the RaspberryPi via USB (example: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/laird-connectivity-inc./BT851/8251358). Alternatively you can buy a new Raspberry Pi or replace your existing one if this is possible.